# iOS app Admob interstitial ad music started playing even if not visible

Tags: ios, admob

In our iOS app we preload the Admob interstial ad like this

```
func loadInterstitialAd(){
    print("loading interstitial ad...")
    let request = GADRequest()
    GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID:adUnitIDInterstitial,
                                request: request,
                      completionHandler: { [self] ad, error in
        if let error = error {
          print("Failed to load interstitial ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
          return
        }
        interstitial = ad
        interstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
        print("interstitial ad loaded")
    })
}
```

It works but recently we noticed that, for some particular ads with background music, the music is audible even if the interstitial ad is just loaded and not visible yet.

How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I have the same issue... It seems to only happen with a Star Trek ad. Did you find a solution?